# Is there a way of storing Jquery fx in a array, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there was a way of storing Jquery fx(e.g. `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`) in a JavaScript array?

here's what I'm attempting on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/c3FQh/

Any help would be appreciated greatly, Thanks

Comment: eh? what do you want to be able to do?

Comment: Um, what do you mean? How do you want to use this?

Comment: I have no clue what you want, so here is an array of functions.  `var arr = [$.fn.fadeIn, $.fn.fadeOut]` or `var arr = [$('body').fadeIn, $('body').fadeOut]`.

Comment: Despite there being correct answers to the question, **PLEASE** tell us why you'd want this!

Comment: here's what I'm attempting on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/c3FQh/

Comment: @Nasir: Can you add that to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're storing the `$.fn` functions in array, you need to call 'em with `.call`.

```
var fxArray = [$.fn.show, $.fn.hide];
var a = fxArray[1];
a.call($('body')); // Same as $('body').hide();
```

Storing the functions in an array is unnecessary, though.  Looking at your code, you just want to call a function using a string as its name.  You can do that like this:

```
var fxq = 'hide';
$('body')[fxq]();  // Same as $('body').hide();
```

Objects in JavaScript can be accessed like arrays using `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fx = [fadeIn,fadeOut];
```

By not including the `()`, you reference the function itself rather than calling it, and in this way you can use it just like any other variable.

Comment: here's what I'm attempting on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/c3FQh/

Comment: When it comes to actually calling the functions you have in the variables, you need to put the `()` in again.

Answer (score 1):

`fadeIn` and `fadeOut` are both functions.

In JavaScript, functions are objects.

Creating an array of objects can be accomplished using this syntax:

```
var fxArray = [$.fn.fadeIn, $.fn.fadeOut];
```

Comment: here's what I'm attempting on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/c3FQh/